# Why doesn't my computed function get added to each item in my knockout observable array?

Tags: knockout.js, ko.observablearray, computed-observable

My observable array has two rows (items ?), row [0] has pid = 2; row[1] has pid = 3.

I am trying to add a field to the observable array called cartItems.   This should be like adding a column to an Excel spreadsheet or to a mathematical matrix.

The following code does not produce any errors but also does not compute the self.myTest value( i5 always gets the default answer of zero..  Why?

```
self.cartItems = ko.mapping.fromJS(cartItems);

    self.myTest = ko.computed(function(){
        var ans =0;
        ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.cartItems, function(item) {
        ans =  ko.utils.unwrapObservable(item.pid());
    });
    return "myTest="+ans;
},self);
```

Comment: Any chance you can throw together a jsfiddle example?

Comment: Joe-- I am trying to create the Fiddle.   I started by copying the one done by Ivan into a new fiddle.  it did not execute for me.  I think that I need to add an External Resource of knockout.mappint-latest-debug.js but do not know how.   The plus button doesn't tell me anything.  Can you advise?

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.cartItems(), ...` instead of `ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.cartItems, ...`. (with `()`). [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ivan_Srb/A3F5j/1/).

**Update:**
Look at updated [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ivan_Srb/A3F5j/3/) to solve your problem with posibility to add new property to row (item).

Comment: In your fiddle array is not observable, so there are no reasons to add `()` (execute) to `self.cartItems` and `item.pid`, and it is working good. But if I correctly understand question ("I am trying to add a field to the observable array") - array should be observable. :)

Comment: I am new to this stuff and so do not totally understand you comments.

Comment: @AnnMaybury My comment was addressed to Joe. For you I've created this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Ivan_Srb/A3F5j/1/ and wrote about your mistake in answer.

Comment: I tried this fiddle and it doesn't work when the array is multidimensional.   It adds what is essentially another (row)=item to your array.   i have an array like this.  var cartItems = [{id:0,pid: 2,ix:5, {id:1,pid: 3,ix:6}];  I want to add a new field in each row (item) so that they array would become

Comment: @AnnMaybury You could update my fiddle with your problem and share link, and than I will try to solve it.

Comment: I am trying to create this fiddle.